# javascript regex: match all words with just some letters

Tags: javascript, regex

So I'm fairly new to regular expressions. Any help is appreciated.

I have a string in the following format:

```
var str: ".item-61347 .item-79134 .item-79465 .item-96464"
```

I want to be able to extract all matching words, given just some input. For example:

```
input: 13 --> .item-61347 .item-79134
input: 79 --> .item-79134 .item-79465
input: 96464 --> .item-96464
```

The input will be a string variable, so ideally I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
str.match(<regexp with string containing input>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
var testRegex, 
    testInputs = [13, 79, 96464];
var testStr   = '.item-61347 .item-79134 .item-79465 .item-96464';
for (var i = 0, l = testInputs.length; i < l; ++i) {
    testRegex = new RegExp('[.]item-(?=[0-9]*' + testInputs[i] + ')[0-9]+', 'ig');
    console.log(testStr.match(testRegex));
}
```

The point is using lookaheads in your regex to simultaneously check the digits subpattern *and* your input in it.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome!!!! If I could give you +100 I would. I'm in a tight deadline at work and have to use this along with jQuery isotope library. Thanks again! God bless

Comment: For input `13`, this would not match `.item-633413`. You may need to replace `[0-9]+` to `[0-9]*`. And make the first `[0-9]*` 'ungreedy' like `[0-9]*?`. What do you think?

Comment: @Kash Did you actually check your example? It's lookahead, not a simple match; kind of 'OR' in regex.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Just tried to make my answer easier to fiddle with. Of course, the loop is not required if input will be taken once only.

Comment: I believe he is just testing each case.

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't look like there is need for a regexp at all:

```
var items = ".item-61347 .item-79134 .item-79465 .item-96464".split(" ");

var itemsThatMatch13 = items.filter( function(v) {
    return v.indexOf("13") > 0;
});

//[".item-61347", ".item-79134"]
```

Comment: @victorswx btw, if you need IE <9 support, you can get the code here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility

Comment: This solution also involves an internal loop that uses your function as a callback.

Comment: @Esailija +1 for elegancy and regexlessness. ) Bbut as you correctly noticed, indexOf requires some additional work for IE8- browsers.

Comment: @raina77ow that is `Array.indexOf` (not used here and needs a shim in ie <9)... [`String.indexOf` (used here and doesn't need a shim)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) works as is. The link is for `Array.filter` :P

Comment: @Esailija Damn. ) Always confusing these.